# How to change directory of gnuplot in linux?

Tags: linux, plot, terminal, gnuplot

I have to do some plot with gnuplot in linux but I can't figure out how to change directory in gnuplot, because cd just in terminal doesn't work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what error you are getting?

Comment: @jww: I don’t see how this question would be less on-topic than most of the other four thousand Gnuplot questions on this site. If you want to declare a considerable amount of these questions off-topic here, I can totally see where you are coming from, but please take it to [meta] instead of taking it out on this question.

Comment: @jww Sorry, but you cannot simply decide, that from now on all gnuplot questions are off-topic!

Comment: Thanks @Christoph - As far as I know, many questions have always been off-topic. It has always been that way. The questions that are related to programming and development are on-topic. How to use the command to make plots are off-topic. The problem seems to be, those who monitor the tag don't follow the site's rules.

Comment: @jww: Whether you are right or not, please take you issue to [meta].

Comment: @ Wrzlprmft - The site rules are clear, and there's no issue to take up. As far as I know there is no exemption for GNUplot. If you can provide a reference to an exemption for GNUplot, then I'd be happy stop moving against the off-topic questions with the tag.

Comment: @jww: If a huge bunch of questions is against the site rules or a considerable number of users acts against the site rules, this is a problem that shouldn’t been discussed on a single question but taken to Meta. That is what Meta is for.

Comment: [I started a Meta discussion.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354086/2127008) (CC @Christoph)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use quotation marks around your directory name:

```
gnuplot> pwd
/home/wrzlprmft

gnuplot> cd "tmp"

gnuplot> pwd
/home/wrzlprmft/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no real need for this, as you can simply do this:

```
plot "../otherDir/samples.dat"
```

Another really helpful thing that I discovered way too late is that this works:

```
plot '<./yourScript.sh input.dat -p someParameter'
```

Also see [this](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/contour.html) bogpost for an example.

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be appreciated...

Comment: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)

Comment: @jww Given the tags 'gnuplot' 'plot' and 'terminal' exist (and that you need 1500 reputation to create new tags), I don't really see how this question can be off topic... 
Also I remember the time when I had issues like physnolimits and had a hard time discovering things like the ones I postet. So I thought it would be just fair to help. But I guess there's always people with stong opinions...

Comment: If you [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), you will see Stack Overflow's mission is to *"... build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"*. This question does not have anything to do with programming or development. If I am parsing things correctly, you are arguing, *"A tag exists, therefore its on-topic"*. One does not lead to the other, and it's not exactly how things work. They could work that way, but the Stack Overflow charter would have to change.